# Yii2: Multiple inverse relations to same model?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-active-records

How do I handle multiple inverse relations pointing to the same active record?
For example:

```php
class Bicycle extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getFrontWheel() {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Wheel::class, ['id' => 'front_wheel_id'])
            ->inverseOf('bicycles');
    }

    public function getRearWheel() {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Wheel::class, ['id' => 'rear_wheel_id'])
            ->inverseOf('bicycles');
    }

}

class Wheel extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getBicycles() {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Bicycle::class, ['???' => 'id'])
            ->inverseOf('??????');
    }

}
```

What can I do here? I critically need the inverse relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution.
Key points:

- It all boils down to proper naming.
- Inverse relations are [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)! In other words, every relation always has to have its own unique mirror relation on the other end.

```php
class Bicycle extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getFrontWheel() {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Wheel::class, ['id' => 'front_wheel_id'])
            ->inverseOf('frontWheelBicycles');
    }

    public function getRearWheel() {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Wheel::class, ['id' => 'rear_wheel_id'])
            ->inverseOf('rearWheelBicycles');
    }

}
```

```php
class Wheel extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getFrontWheelBicycles() {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Bicycle::class, ['front_wheel_id' => 'id'])
            ->inverseOf('frontWheel');
    }

    public function getRearWheelBicycles() {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Bicycle::class, ['rear_wheel_id' => 'id'])
            ->inverseOf('rearWheel');
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest to do the following:

create two new classes:

- class FrontWheel extends Wheel {
- class RearWheel extends Wheel {

in new classes you can set easily the relation.

How to instantiate the correct class? There is a method in ActiveRecord [instantiate()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#instantiate()-detail) where you can write your logic which wheel class need to be created.

```
class Wheel extends ActiveRecord {
...

  public static function instantiate ( $row ) {
      if($row['type'] === 'RearWheel') {
           return new RealWheel();
      }
      ...

  }
```

full code:

```
class Bicycle extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function getFrontWheel()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Wheel::class, ['id' => 'front_wheel_id'])
            ->inverseOf('bicycles');
    }

    public function getRearWheel()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Wheel::class, ['id' => 'rear_wheel_id'])
            ->inverseOf('bicycles');
    }

}

abstract class Wheel extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function instantiate($row)
    {
        if ($row['type'] === 'RearWheel') {
            return new RealWheel();
        }
        if ($row['type'] === 'FrontWheel') {
            return new FrontWheel();
        }
        
        throw new InvalidConfigException();
    }

    abstract public function getBicycles();
}

class RealWheel extends Wheel
{

    public function getBicycles()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Bicycle::class, ['rear_wheel_id' => 'id'])
            ->inverseOf('rearWheel');
    }

}

class FrontWheel extends Wheel
{

    public function getBicycles()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Bicycle::class, ['front_wheel_id' => 'id'])
            ->inverseOf('frontWheel');
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting idea but it won't work. The wheels cannot have a "`type`" property, because they must be usable in either location (rear or front) without any modification.

Comment: Hi, if you cannot use type, you could query your db inside instantiate method where that id belongs, if it belongs to a front_wheel_id then you can instantate the front wheel class. I know it is an extra query, i think that is needed in your case. Think about this: Can you tell from a wheel without context (bike) whether it's a front or rear wheel?

Comment: Indeed, you cannot and you *should not* be able to. A wheel is a wheel.

Comment: So what do you think about querying for it in instantiate method?

Comment: That sounds like a performance hit, which defeats the whole purpose of inverse relations. Either way, I've found an elegant solution. I will post my answer in a couple of days unless someone proposes something better.